# over-flow:hidden makes my content hiding behind ans z-index is not working

Tags: html, css

Here in the above html content, `class="scroll"` will have style `overflow-x: hidden` and because of that my `class="tool-tip"` content is hiding behind the div. Even I tried to make `class="tool-tip"` z-index more, but it is not working.

```css
.scroll {
  position: fixed;
  left: 216px;
  top: 178px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  bottom: 0%;
  z-index: 999;
}
.tool-tip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div clas="scroll"> 
  <span class="tooltip-text right">
    <span class="text">
      5978486 GGGG 1234 rrrr 1257 vvvv bbbb tttt 12
    </span>
    <span class="tool-tip">
      5978486 GGGG 1234 rrrr 1257 vvvv bbbb tttt 12
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: `z-index` have no effect on overflow, it have only effect on overlay, can you please provide more code?

Comment: At least provide us with your CSS if your question relates to CSS.

Comment: assign a position to your class tooltip and see if z-index starts to work. `position:relative;` or `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are missing an 'S' from the word class on your first div.

Second you don't need to specify a top and bottom attribute on your fixed element. use one or the other.

If you apply a top and left attribute to your absolute positioned span that will also help put it in the correct place.

However to make it so you can't see the text, you will need a background colour or something to make it opaque so that the absolute span does not show through.

I hope these all make sense.

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/ky3gxr5w/)

```css
.scroll {
  position: fixed;
  left: 216px;
  top: 178px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 999;
 
}
  .text {
    display: block;
    background: red;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
  }
.tool-tip {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll"> 
  <span class="tooltip-text right">
    <span class="text">
      5978486 GGGG 1234 rrrr 1257 vvvv bbbb tttt 12
    </span>
    <span class="tool-tip">
      test content
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```